# Compiled executable causes "exec format error" at run-time

Tags: windows, gcc, fortran, gfortran

I have a Fortran project which is cross-platform based and can be successfully compiled under Windows (tested with Win7 32bit and Win10 64bit) by gfortran (tested with 4.9 and 5.3).
However, the compiled executable cannot run and gives "Exec format error" whenever executed.

I also used `file` to check the compiled version and the result does show something like "PE32 executable (console) Intel 80386, for MS Windows".

The program can be successfully compiled and executed under Linux and Mac.

So, what is the problem?

Comment: Yes, I'm running the executable compiled on the same Windows environment. Actually, the project is being worked within Netbeans, so all the procedures like compilation, execution, etc. are done in a row.

Comment: And what other information do you need at the moment?

Comment: we use cygwin and these flags: `-g -w -Wall -Wtabs -fbounds-check`.

Comment: Thanks for your patience. We just located the problem, which turned out to be the limitation in the total size of static arrays. When we reduced the sizes of those arrays, the program could run happily.

Comment: Also, in order to enrich the details of this case, I put some more words here. @d_1999, yes, we tried to compile it outside of Netbeans (i.e., under Cygwin) in the way as under Linux shell and didn't succeed.

Comment: Ah ok, I came across something along these lines when I was researching this but I now can't find the relevant question. You may want to consider answering your own question now that you have found the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

We just located the problem, which turned out to be the limitation in the total size of static arrays specific to Windows (tested with Win7 32bit and Win10 64bit).

When we reduced the sizes of those arrays, the program could run happily.